# Get sender email using SOOD table

Tags: abap

I am trying to get the sender email adress of the entries saved in the table SOOD in SAP. I need to get this info via tables. I have seen that there might be some FM, like so_object_read, that can achieve so, but I need to relate those two fields via tables.

This table stores the info that appears in SCOT trx (SOIN - received messages and SOST sent messages).

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can reach message sender if you have SOOD record:

```
SELECT sost~objtp, sost~objno, sost~objyr, sost~msgv2 
  FROM sood 
  LEFT JOIN sost 
    ON sood~objtp = sost~objtp 
   AND sood~objno = sost~objno 
   AND sood~objyr = sost~objyr 
  INTO TABLE it_sost.
```

Sender is contained in **MSGV2** and recipient in **MSGV1** of `SOST` table.

[image]

The same logic should be used with `SOIN` table.

Comment: This would do it in a single select:

`SELECT sost~objtp, sost~objno, sost~objyr, sost~msgv2 FROM sood
  LEFT JOIN sost
    ON sood~objtp = sost~objtp
    AND sood~objno = sost~objno
    AND sood~objyr = sost~objyr
  INTO TABLE it_sost`

Comment: @Suncatcher Thank you so much! I already found that relation. However, I do not have every SOOD entry in the SOST table, neither in the SOIN one. Do you know why could this be happening?

Comment: @Samleijenhorst Thank you so much!! Do you know why what I told to suncather could be happening?